# How to make a minipage break over two pages<

Tags: minipage, fbox, frame

I have an example of communication in mz document in a separate frame, for which I used fbox + minipage. How can I make it break over 2 pages? MWE below, I left all packages used, in case they interfere.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 top=22mm,
 bottom=22mm,
 inner=35.6mm,
 outer=35.6mm
 }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,
sorting=nty,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{Sources.bib}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} 
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks
  \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
  \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
  \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
  \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
  \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
  \do\Y\do\Z\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%
    
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Huge} % format
{\thechapter} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code


\setlength{\parskip}{0,5 em}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\linespread{1}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
\begin{center}
\textbf{Guardian}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Griffin, this is Guardian, prepare to receive five liner. Over.\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\textbf{Griffin}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Guardian, this is Griffin, send traffic. Over.\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\textbf{Guardian}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Requesting strike on one times truck, SE of our location, close.\\
Marker on map, grid 189235.\\
Guns only.\\
No remarks. Over.\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\textbf{Griffin}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Guardian, this is Griffin. Copy.\\
Strike on one times truck, SE of ground units, close.\\
Marker on map, grid 189235.\\
Guns only.\\
No remarks. Over.\\
\vspace*{2mm}
\textbf{Guardian}\\
\vspace*{2mm}
Good readback.\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\textit{*Splash strike}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
Good effect, break. Over and out.
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{center}
\captionof{figure}{An example of communication}

\par
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Thank you and have a wonderful day.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. If you want to use `\fbox+minipage` with `breaking`, then try with `\usepackage{framed}....\begin{framed}...\end{framed}`

Comment: The tcolorbox package offers framed boxes that can break over pages, fbox can't.

Comment: By default a minipage cannot break across pages. You might consider using two (or more) minipages.

Comment: The code that you showed is far of be a  MWE (with "M" of "minimal"). This discourages modifying it to show you a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

`minipages` are not split between pages. Alternatively, you can use the `framed` environment provided by the `framed` package.

The width of the frame can be changed by adding an optional parameter to that environment.

```
\renewenvironment{framed}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=22mm,
    bottom=22mm,
    inner=35.6mm,
    outer=35.6mm
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=authoryear,
citestyle=authoryear,
sorting=nty,
maxcitenames=2
]{biblatex}
%%\addbibresource{Sources.bib}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} 
\expandafter\def\expandafter\UrlBreaks\expandafter{\UrlBreaks
    \do\a\do\b\do\c\do\d\do\e\do\f\do\g\do\h\do\i\do\j%
    \do\k\do\l\do\m\do\n\do\o\do\p\do\q\do\r\do\s\do\t%
    \do\u\do\v\do\w\do\x\do\y\do\z\do\A\do\B\do\C\do\D%
    \do\E\do\F\do\G\do\H\do\I\do\J\do\K\do\L\do\M\do\N%
    \do\O\do\P\do\Q\do\R\do\S\do\T\do\U\do\V\do\W\do\X%
    \do\Y\do\Z\do\*\do\-\do\~\do\'\do\"\do\-}%

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\bfseries\Huge} % format
{\thechapter} % label
{1ex} % sep
{} % before-code
[] % after-code


\setlength{\parskip}{0,5 em}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}

\linespread{1}

%******************************************* added <<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{framed}
\renewenvironment{framed}[1][\hsize]
{\MakeFramed{\hsize#1\advance\hsize-\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
%*******************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Test}
    \blindtext
    \blindtext
    
    \begin{center}
%       \fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
                \begin{framed}[0.9\linewidth] % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
                \begin{center}
                    \textbf{Guardian}\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    Griffin, this is Guardian, prepare to receive five liner. Over.\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    \textbf{Griffin}\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    Guardian, this is Griffin, send traffic. Over.\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    \textbf{Guardian}\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    Requesting strike on one times truck, SE of our location, close.\\
                    Marker on map, grid 189235.\\
                    Guns only.\\
                    No remarks. Over.\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    \textbf{Griffin}\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    Guardian, this is Griffin. Copy.\\
                    Strike on one times truck, SE of ground units, close.\\
                    Marker on map, grid 189235.\\
                    Guns only.\\
                    No remarks. Over.\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    \textbf{Guardian}\\
                    \vspace*{2mm}
                    Good readback.\\
                    \vspace{0.5cm}
                    \textit{*Splash strike}\\
                    \vspace{0.5cm}
                    Good effect, break. Over and out.
                \end{center}
            \end{framed} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%       \end{minipage}}
    \captionof{figure}{An example of communication} % here
    \end{center}
    
    \par
    \blindtext
\end{document}
```